# List files in ListBox without filepath in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to list files into a ListBox with

`Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(CurDir, "*.txt")`

For the ListBox I use

`ListBox1.Items.AddRange(files)`

But it returns with a full path, how would I be able to only get the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options. If you wanted to stick as closely as possible to what you already have, you can call `Path.GetFileName` for each file path, e.g.

```vb
Dim filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(CurDir, "*.6eamed")
Dim fileNames = Array.ConvertAll(filePaths, Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s))

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(fileNames)
```

I would go with a slightly different approach though. I'd suggest that you use `DirectoryInfo`, `FileInfo` and data-binding:

```vb
Dim folder = New DirectoryInfo(CurDir)
Dim files = folder.GetFiles("*.6eamed")

With ListBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "FullName"
    .DataSource = files
End With
```

The user will now see just the file names, but you can get the full path for the selected item from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: Awesome, the first option seems to be working properly for what I need. Thank you so much!